# Does GetType() and typeof() constitute reflection?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# reflection invariably starts with:

```
myInstance.GetType();
```

Or:

```
typeof(MyType);
```

To get the `Type`, then when one queries the info about the type e.g. getting properties, fields, attributes etc. they are certainly performing reflection.

However are the above calls reflection themselves?

I suppose in a academic sense the answer is yes - because you are reflecting on the type. So my second part to the question is: *is it evaluated at run time and does it perform a heap allocation the first time?* (I know subsequent calls to `GetType()` on the same type return the same `Type` instance so .NET must cache the result - but did it have to construct a new Type the first time it was called? Or this something performed at compile time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object returned by `myInstance.GetType()` or `typeof(MyType)` is an object on the managed heap. So at some point at *runtime* the allocation must be made. The compiler obviously cannot do a managed heap allocation. (This is in contrast to C/C++ 'functions' like `sizeof`, where a value is substituted in by the compiler, resulting in no runtime overhead at all.)

So from this, you can conclude that the `Type` objects are either created at the point your assembly is loaded, or created 'on-demand' when you invoke methods like `myInstance.GetType()` or `typeof(MyType)` for the first time.

Which of these is it? As far as I know, it's not specified, so it's hard to say. `GetType()`, for example, is implemented in the runtime itself:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

Either way, at some point there will have to be the (*extremely small*) runtime overhead of allocating the `Type` object for `MyType` on the managed heap.

Comment: I wonder if `Type`s are special and created when the assembly is loaded, but as you say: its hard to say!

Comment: @markmnl: If I had to *guess*, I'd say probably at assembly load. It would make more sense to me that way. But whether the guess is right or wrong, it's (afaik) unspecified - so it's probably best not to rely on these kind of implementation details!