# Is this considered reflection?

Tags: java, c#, reflection

I had a job interview today and I was asked, if the code below is a good example/case of using reflection in `C#`:

```
public abstract class Level{

    public string LevelID { get; private set;}
    public int LevelNumber {
        get{
            return int.Parse(LevelID.Substring(5).ToString());
        }
    }

    public Level(){
        this.LevelID = GetType().ToString();
    }

}
```

I assume the use of the code above would be:

```
class Level32 : Level{
    // call base class constructor...
}
```

and then

```
Level32 level = new Level32(); 
int id = level.LevelNumber; // would print 32.
```

I think the guy meant this line: `this.LevelID = GetType().ToString();`

I said that there's no reflection at all.

As good as I know `Java`, calling `SomeClass.class.getName()` does not use any of the 'reflective' packages, so it doesn't use reflection at all. I thought that `C#` is built that way too.

Am I dumb, or he is?

Comment: I see no meaningful use of what I would call reflection there.  Parsing a string and reading a type name are pretty common operations.  The former much more than the latter of course, but still common and not "reflection".  As you imply, "reflection" is pretty easily identified by the use of things in `System.Reflection`.  And, more conceptually, examining the inner workings of objects beyond what's provided on the surface interface.  Which isn't happening here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does GetType() and typeof() constitute reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376879/does-gettype-and-typeof-constitute-reflection)

Comment: If you want to frame the question that way, I'd say you are the dumb one. `GetType()` is reflection, at least conceptually, if not in namespace.

Comment: I agree Blorgbeard, as reflection means getting (=reflecting) information about types.

Comment: That code only has a tiny tiny taste of what can Reflection be or do. But yes, you can say so.

Comment: First, I think it's a dumb question to ask. It servers zero purpose except in terms of performance, which in this case is probably negligible for this particular example. Second, he should have further qualified and if he did not, you should have asked him to. Third, I guess you could consider the `GetType()` call to be reflection, since the premise is that you are calling that method because you don't know what the type is (regardless of the inner workings).

Comment: Ambiguous question though - "a good example of using reflection in C#"? - Well, I wouldn't use it as an example.

Comment: @NightOwl888 It's clear now that `GetType()` is considered reflection, but still - I disagree with that this is a good example of using it. I was taught that using reflection in a classic OOP apps like this one (I assume that it would be a game) is a bad practice, no matter what. And I'll stick with that.

Comment: What does "good example" mean?  This code is atrocious so I'd call it a bad example period, even if one could argue that it is an example of Reflection. If the question is, "does this example demonstrate the underlying concept of Reflection well?" then I'd also say no.  The only thing you could say a begruding "yes" to is, "Is this an example of reflection?" because, although the reflection libraries might not be invoked, the concept of reflection is in use.

Comment: You could've told them to use the `nameof` operator.

Answer (score 7):

I think that, strictly speaking, the `GetType()` call is reflection, yes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377353/8261

However, it is only the most trivial reflection, so I wouldn't think you were "a "Hello World" kid" for discounting it. :-)

> Am I dumb, or he is?

I don't like this framing: it seems to me that neither of you are (or perhaps both of you are, for getting into an argument over trivial semantics).

Answer (score 3):

First sentences from Microsoft docs:

> Reflection provides objects (of type Type) that describe assemblies, modules and types. You can use reflection to dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, **or get the type from an existing object**

Method `GetType()` returns object of type `Type` and is used (obviously) to "get the type from an existing object". Looking only at those rules we can say it is reflection.

To be clear, I consider this a bad question for interview, there a better ways to check if candidate understands reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputations to add comments. Please don't mind me adding it as an answer. :)
We already have a few good answers about **GetType()**.

I'd like to answer "is a good example/**case** of using reflection?".

I think the intended answer is "No".

The keywords here are **abstract** and **GetType()**. The point of creating abstract classes and interfaces is that the caller doesn't have to know what the **exact type** it is.

If we still have to know the actual type of the **sub-classes**, we're not using it correctly.

So I think this is not really a question about reflection. It's more like a question about **OOP/inheritance**.

That's just my 2 cents.